# Strange behavior on Azure ASP NET Core Mvc AJAX JSON POST

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, azure

I have found something completely strange and I think i'm going crazy.

I'm Simply trying to POST json by ajax to a controller and receive some JSON back. The responding JSON is missing the } at the end causing an error.

Here is the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("TerminalUpdatePocket")',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                pocketRef: pocketRef,
                terminalID: terminalID
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                showSnackbarWithMessage("Active pocket updated successfully");
            },
            error: function (){
                showSnackbarWithMessage("An error occured while updating active pocket");
            }
        }).done(function (result) {
            $(button).attr("disabled", "false");
            $('#pockets-modal').modal('hide');
        });
```

Here is the Controller function:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TerminalUpdatePocket([FromBody]TerminalUpdatePocketViewModel vm)
    {
        Terminal terminal = terminalService.updateTerminalPocket(vm.terminalID, vm.pocketRef);


        if(terminal != null)
        {
            string pocketName = FundiCard.Utilities.PocketType.getPocketName((int)vm.pocketRef);
            var dataObj = new
            {
                pocketName = pocketName,
                pocketRef = ((int)vm.pocketRef),
                terminalNumber = terminal.TerminalNumber
            };

            return Json(dataObj);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

Here is the Call overview: As you can see everything has the correct Content-Type headers etc:
[image]

Here is the request payload as expected in JSON:
[image]

And finally here is the response:
[image]

As you can see, the response is missing the } at the end causing a JSON parse error on the js side. Note that this only happens on Azure (not when hosted locally or anywhere else for that matter). This is driving me mad! Any any any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is very, very odd behaviour. Have you overridden the JsonResult, or use any server-side processing on the response?

Comment: Not on JSON, I have added an OutputFormatter but thats only for "application/x-protobuf" content types. I can paste its code if you like.

Comment: Yes please. That's the only thing I could see that could affect this. Also, can you return JSON from other endpoints, or is it just this one that has the problem?

Comment: Here is my ProtobufOutputFormatter http://pastebin.com/GdYJZYQP. I have plenty other endpoints that work just fine. Also the response has the } when I run it locally using visual studio. I can paste the local response so that you can see aswell. Its only azure that causes this. Im thinking its some sort of Content Length cache or something.

Comment: That's even weirder then. It's unlikely to be your code if you're successfully returning JSON elsewhere. It's also unlikely to be due to content length or cache as I use Azure to return much larger payloads from APIs. I'm at a loss really. I'd try contacting support if you can. Sorry I couldn't be any more help.

Comment: I just used another computer (mac chrome) and it returns the same result except its also missing the " : {"pocketName":"Food","pocketRef":2,"terminalNumber":"d70e3841        truncated 2 characters instead of 1

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan after about 8 hours of straight struggling I found the issue and you would never believe me :O.  Inside the updateTerminalPocket function dbContext.saveChangesAsync was called but not awaited. Changing this to dbContext.saveChanes made the json return correctly. Must be some completely crazy race condition causing the response to be cut short on the web app platform of azure.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed :)